# Prove that $(\Bbb{R},+)$ is isomorphic to $(\Bbb{C},+)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Prove that $(\Bbb{R},+)$ is isomorphic to $(\Bbb{C},+)$.

I don't know how to proceed in this question. On doing a customary internet search, I found that this can be proven using Axiom of Choice. Does there not exist an explicit isomorphism?

Comment: They both are $\;\Bbb Q$ - linear spaces. What is their dimension?

Comment: @Timbuc- How do I prove that they have the same dimension?

Comment: Take into account the cardinality of $\;\Bbb Q\,,\,\,\Bbb R\,,\,\,\Bbb C\;$